# Do any denominations teach that Adam and Eve had children in the Garden of Eden?

Tags: denomination-survey, adam-and-eve, children, garden-of-eden

In the Garden of Eden, God commands Adam and Eve to

> "Be fruitful and increase in number" Genesis 1:28 (NIV)

Later, after the Fall in Genesis 3, we're told that

> "Adam made love to his wife Eve, and she became pregnant and gave birth to Cain" Genesis 4:1 (NIV)

The Bible does not tell us the time difference between these two events, or even clearly state that Cain's birth happened after the fall (although it's *implied* by the order it is recorded).

Do any Christian denominations or beliefs teach that Adam and Eve produced children (Cain, Abel, or others) while they were in the Garden of Eden?

Comment: It is clear from his behaviour that Cain was a fallen creature, which is significant to the question.

Comment: You must mean in context of a literal Adam, Garden, and Fall. In that case, I don't think there's any Christian sects that believe more than Adam and Eve fell in the Garden.

Comment: Adam and Eve had many children, but most likely outside of the Garden of Eden.